# Prevent object checking by Garbage Collector

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

In my program, I use a `HashSet` which I will only put objects in, which I will `never` get out again. The entries are classes and there could get over a 100,000 entries in the set. Memory use is not a problem here, but the garbage collector is. 45% of my cpu goes to garbage collecting, and I suspect this is because of the large set.

Is there a way to have the garbage collector `not` check an object? I never want to remove the objects in the set.

Comment: what makes u so sure that GC is using 45% of CPU?

Comment: What about storing your objects in a file for example?

Comment: @Deffiss How file will help here? They are stored in a HashSet for quick access I guess...

Comment: @Igor S. It depends on his business logic.

Comment: Think we can safely say you've missed something out of your question, or you've misunderstood what's going on GC wise. Get a profiler on it. If just stopping the GC messing with it was a viable the solution, the GC wouldn't be messing with it....

Comment: What do you mean you will never get out again?

Comment: Sorry I away for some time. I am never getting the objects 'out of the set', by which I mean a reference to the object will always remain inside the set for the duration of the whole program. The garbage colector could skip the object, but it seems like it does this already, according to Igor S's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET uses generational garbage collection and considering your scenario, it will eventually move all objects to generation 2, which is rarely collected.
So unless those objects are being replaced very frequently, GC shouldn't be an issue.

I'd go for a memory profiler to see what exactly is being collected if you're 100% sure that GC eats 45% CPU